# why jquery load() method doesn't require a webserver to work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

why jquery load() method doesn't require a webserver to work properly , although ajax requires a web server .!!? isn't load a wrapper to simplify ajax activities?

thanks :)

**edit:** it's now clear  , thank you

Comment: What exactly do you mean? it *does* require a web server, unless you're loading the file from your local computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are loading content from "somewhere" on the web, it doesn't matter if you have a web server or not, since you might be loading from Google, or Digg, or StackOverflow, etc.

AJAX doesn't require that you provide the web server... just that a web server somewhere exists to load up the content.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is a JavaScript library and thus a completely client side code. It runs entirely in the browser. While it does make AJAX easier it is not only for that. Even so, AJAX does not require a webserver either.